# Networkx gives attributes as neighbors

Tags: networkx

I need to mark nodes as visited in a traversal I'm doing. So I do `G[node]['visited'] = True`. However, this messes up `G.neighbors(node)`, giving me `'visited'` as a neighbor of `node`! What is the approriate way to handle this?

Example:

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> G = nx.Graph()
>>> G.add_edge(0,1)
>>> G[0]['visited'] = True
>>> G.neighbors(0)
['visited', 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `G[0]['visited'] = True` use `G.node[0]['visited'] = True`.

Example for what you want. You can check the attribute value in the same way you set it.

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> G = nx.Graph()
>>> G.add_edge(0,1)
>>> G.node[0]['visited'] = True
>>> G.neighbors(0)
[1]
>>> G.node[0]['visited']
True
```

Comment: Ah. Looks good! And then if I want to do edge attributes, would I do e.g. `G.edge[u][v]['flow']=50`?

Comment: Yes. Here you can use `G.edge[u][v]['flow'] = 50` or `G[u][v]['flow'] = 50`.

Comment: But the latter messes up the adjacency list, right?